# Filtering items based on selected dropdown

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an aspnet core app for selling albums. I want to add the option to filter the albums based on genre. I have the following code in my controller and when I type out the variable "genre=pop" in the browser I get the results but I can't seem to get it working with a dropdown or any other thing html-wise. :

```
public ViewResult Genre(string genre)
    {
        string _genre = genre;
        IEnumerable<Album> albums;


        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(genre))
        {
            albums = _albumRepository.Albums.OrderBy(p => p.AlbumId);

        }
        else
        {
            albums = _albumRepository.Albums.Where(p =>
            p.Genre.ToLower().Equals(_genre.ToLower()));
        }

        return View("~/Views/Album/List.cshtml", new AlbumListViewModel {Albums = albums});
    }
```

Comment: Do you need server side filtering? If you are populating all you data at once to your table, you could use JQuery filter:https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_filters.asp or a DataTable plugin: https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html depending on your requirement

Comment: You should post a minimal example of the HTML that you are using where the drop down list is not sending correctly to the controller.

Comment: You could skip the if/else with a single linq `.Where(p => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(genre) || p.Genre == genre).OrderBy(p => p.AlbumId)` - I think IsNullOrWhiteSpace is better, otherwise a bunch of white spaces could lead to unintended response

Comment: Check [Add search by genre to the Index view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/search?view=aspnetcore-2.2#add-search-by-genre-to-the-index-view)